# Error convert docx to pdf in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

Good afternoon all,

Come to my case, I'm generating a docx document Junction 2 other docx, I'm doing a merge.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Clientes\\Constremac\\Repositorio_DOCS\\UPLOAD\\LAYOUT_PAGINA_VERSAO_FINAL.docx"));
    InputStream in2 = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Clientes\\Constremac\\Repositorio_DOCS\\UPLOAD\\modeloContratoSocial.docx"));
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Clientes\\Constremac\\Repositorio_DOCS\\UPLOAD\\modeloContratoSocialMerge.docx"));
    mergeDocx(in1,in2,out);
}

 public static void mergeDocx(InputStream s1, InputStream s2, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage target = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(s1);
    insertDocx(target.getMainDocumentPart(), IOUtils.toByteArray(s2));
    SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(target);
    saver.save(os);
}
private static void insertDocx(MainDocumentPart main, byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/part" + (chunk++) + ".docx"));
        afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType(CONTENT_TYPE));
        afiPart.setBinaryData(bytes);
        Relationship altChunkRel = main.addTargetPart(afiPart);
        //convertAltChunks()
        CTAltChunk chunk = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
        chunk.setId(altChunkRel.getId());

        main.addObject(chunk);
}
```

My final document (docx) is ok, I can open it normally. The problem occurs when I will convert this generated file to PDF, the following error appears: NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for w: altChunk -.

```
public boolean createPDF(String nomeArquivo)    {
    try     {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Configuration confg = new Configuration();

        System.out.println(Configuration.repositorioUpload + nomeArquivo + ".docx");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(Configuration.repositorioUpload + nomeArquivo + ".docx"));
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);

        PdfSettings pdfSettings = new PdfSettings();

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Configuration.repositorioUpload + nomeArquivo + ".pdf"));
        PdfConversion converter = new Conversion(wordMLPackage);
        converter.output(out, pdfSettings);

        System.err.println("Generate " + Configuration.repositorioUpload  + nomeArquivo + ".pdf" + " with " + (
                System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm sending the java code i use, for a while I'm trying to generate this pdf, if anyone able to help me I am grateful.

Thank you all.

Hugs!

---

I found a way to use AltChunck, but even beyond not run correctly merge the images footer and header when exported to PDF does not appear.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    boolean ADD_TO_HEADER = true;
    HeaderPart hp = null;

    String inputfilepath = "C:\\Clientes\\Constremac\\Repositorio_DOCS\\UPLOAD\\default_template.xml";

    String chunkPath = "C:\\Clientes\\Constremac\\Repositorio_DOCS\\UPLOAD\\sample.docx";

    boolean save = true;
    String outputfilepath =  "C:\\Clientes\\Constremac\\Repositorio_DOCS\\UPLOAD\\altChunk_out.docx";


    // Open a document from the file system
    // 1. Load the Package
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
    //proce
    MainDocumentPart main = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

    if (ADD_TO_HEADER) {
        hp = wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections().get(0).getHeaderFooterPolicy().getDefaultHeader();
    }

    AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/chunk.docx"));
    afiPart.setBinaryData(new FileInputStream(chunkPath));

    afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml")); //docx
    //afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("application/xhtml+xml")); //xhtml

    Relationship altChunkRel = null;
    if (ADD_TO_HEADER) {
        altChunkRel = hp.addTargetPart(afiPart);
    } else {
        altChunkRel = main.addTargetPart(afiPart);          
    }

    CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
    ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId());

    if (ADD_TO_HEADER) {
        hp.getJaxbElement().getEGBlockLevelElts().add(ac);
    } else {
        main.addObject(ac);
    }

    // Save it

    if (save) {     
        SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(wordMLPackage);
        saver.save(outputfilepath);
        System.out.println("Saved " + outputfilepath);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

An altChunk is not "real" docx content.

Before it can be outputted in PDF, it needs to be replaced with normal WordML paragraphs, tables etc.

You can try doing this yourself, which is easy enough if the content does not include any relationships (images, hyperlinks etc), or conflicting styles or numbering.  Please see further http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2010/11/merging-word-documents/ .. or my company's website [plutext.com](http://www.plutext.com/m/index.php/products)

Comment: Hi JasonPlutext, thanks for the reply, I'm more like a doubt, I will perform this procedure after this line: 

  converter.output (Oct, pdfSettings); 

And as I declare this public process WordprocessingMLPackage (WordprocessingMLPackage srcPackage)? 

Can you give me an example? 

Thanks for the help. 

Hugs!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved

An altChunk is not "real" docx content.

using java we can convert altchunk to original content word tags,

convert the document.xml inside docx

```
Docx4jProperties.setProperty(“docx4j.Convert.Out.HTML.OutputMethodXML”,
true);
Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
```

Open the link for complete code.

[Convert AltChunk To Original Content][1]

https://kishankichi.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/convert-altchunk-to-original-content-or-convert-to-real-docx-format-using-java

https://kishankichi.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/convert-altchunk-to-original-content-or-convert-to-real-docx-format-using-java/

Note:

Kindly ignore &nbsp and other such tags in your html content.
I have checked only for &nbsp.

Thanks for the replay...